# Как остановить поток в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

У меня есть такой код:

```
Thread(target = autoclick_load).start()
```

Мне нужен код который может закрыть этот поток, при условии что их может быть больше одного и ещё есть работающий tkinter gui который должен остатся.

Comment: Поток нельзя остановить

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит попробовать добавить флаг остановки потока и периодически проверять его -- вот пример кода:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528